# How to extract a substring in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am new in perl and need your help.

I am reading the contents of files in a directory.
I need to extract the substring from the files containing `*.dat`

Sample strings:

```
1) # **   Template Name: IFDOS_ARCHIVE.dat

2) # **  profile for IFNEW_UNIX_CMD.dat template  **

3) # ** Template IFWIN_MV.dat **
```

Need to Extract:

```
1) IFDOS_ARCHIVE.dat

2) IFNEW_UNIX_CMD.dat

3) IFWIN_MV.dat
```

My code:

```
if(open(my $jobprofile, "./profiles/$vitem[0].profile")) {
   my @jobprofiletemp = <$jobprofile>;
   close($jobprofile);
   @proftemplates = grep /.dat/,@jobprofiletemp;

   my $strproftemp = $proftemplates[0];
   my ($tempksh) = $strproftemp =~ / ([^_]*)./;
   print "tempksh: $tempksh","\n";
} else { warn  "problem opening ./$_\n\n"; }
```

my regex is not working.
what do you suggest?

Comment: Check here :- https://regex101.com/r/jQ0oZ1/1  
You can use `$1` to retrieve the first captured group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
open my $fh,"<","file.txt";

while (<$fh>)
{   
    next if /^\s+/; #skip the loop for empty line 
    ($match) = /\s(\w+\.dat)/g; # group the matching word and store the input into the $match
    print "$match\n";
}
```

or simply try the perl one liner

```
perl -ne'    print $1,"\n" if (m/(\w+\.dat)/)    ' file.txt
```

Or you are working in linux try the linux command for to do it

```
grep -ohP '\w+\.dat' one.txt
```

`o`  display the matched element only

`h` for display the output without filename

`P` for perl regex

Comment: thanks for answering. i tried your regex for $match and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be better with something like:

```
while (<$jobprofile>) {
  if ( /(\S+)\.dat/ ) {
    print "$1\n";
  }
}
```

(the `while` is there to make sure you parse every single line)

The regular expressions looks for a sequence of non-white-space characters (`\S`) followed by `.dat`.

The parenthesis surrounding `\S+` capture the match of that part into the special variable `$1`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your regex and I got the correct substring without .dat. i can just concatenate .dat on a latter part of my code.

Comment: I thought you didn't need the `.dat`. If you want it you can move the `)` to after `.dat`, as in `/(\S+\.dat)/`. It's the parenthesis that are capturing the match into the special variable.